# Loading default text string to a table by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I’ve made a form where I want the users to be able to add books (title, author, isbn).

```
<fieldset>
      <legend>Bokdata</legend>
      <label for="txtBookTitle">Tittel</label>
      <input id="txtBookTitle" type="text" value="">
      <label for="txtBookAuthor">Forfatter</label>
      <input id="txtBookAuthor" type="text" value="">
      <label for="txtBookISBN">ISBN</label>
      <input id="txtBookISBN" type="text" value="">
      <p>
        <button onclick="addBookClick()">Legg til</button>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
```

The books will appear in this table:

```
  <table border="2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3">
            Min bokliste
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Tittel</th>
          <th>Forfatter</th>
          <th>ISBN</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tblBodyList">

      </tbody>
      <tfoot id="tblSummary">

      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Adding books by using the input-fields is done by this function:

```
    function addBookClick(){
      //Input fra skjemaet
      var txtBookTitle = document.getElementById("txtBookTitle").value;
      var txtBookAuthor  = document.getElementById("txtBookAuthor").value;
      var txtBookISBN = document.getElementById("txtBookISBN").value;

      // Lag html-tabell
      // 0 = tabell 1
      var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

      // Legg til ny rad nederst i tabellen. (0) = øverste rad i tabellen.
      var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

      // Legg til celler i tabellen
      var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
      var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
      var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

      // Legg til values i cellene
      cel1.innerHTML = txtBookTitle;
      cel2.innerHTML = txtBookAuthor;
      cel3.innerHTML = txtBookISBN;
  }
```

I’m trying to insert some text into a table without html, but by javascript instead. The easiest would of course be to write the text in the table, but this is a school assignment, and I’m not allowed to do that. Getting help is allowed. I hope I’m close to something, but I could really use some advice. I’ve tried the last two days to get a grip on this:

```
var txtBookTitle = document.getElementById("txtBookTitle");
var txtBookAuthor  = document.getElementById("txtBookAuthor");
var txtBookISBN = document.getElementById("txtBookISBN");
var tblBodyList = document.getElementById("tblBodyList");

var books = [];

  var defaultBooks =
    "Judo Unleashed,Neil Ohlenkamp,0-07-147534-6\n"+
    "Kodokan Judo,Jigoro Kano,0-87011-681-9\n"+
    "Olympic Judo,Neil Adams,0-7207-1735-3";

var book = {
  title: "txtBookTitle",
  author: "txtBookAuthor",
  ISBN:   "txtBookISBN"
};

function createBook(title, author, ISBN){
      var Book = {};
      Book.title = title;
      Book.author = author;
      Book.ISBN = ISBN;
      books.push(Book);
      return Book
  }

    var judo = "";
    var kodokan = "";
    var olympic = "";

function loadDefaultBooks(){
      judo = createBook("Judo Unleashed", "Neil Ohlenkamp", "0-07-147534-6");
      kodokan = createBook("Kodokan Judo", "Jigoro Kano", "0-87011-681-9");
      olympic = createBook("Olympic Judo" , "Neil Adams" , "0-7207-1735-3");
    listBooks();
  }
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you are stuck? That will help to understand what your problem is and how to solve that.

Comment: what precisely do you need advice about? What problem are you facing? It's unclear what you want us to help with, exactly.

Comment: Sorry about that! I can't get the list of books var defaultBooks to be added to the table

Comment: well mainly you're never calling the loadDefaultBooks() function, so it simply never executes. And we don't know what listBooks() does so it's unclear if there's a problem in there somewhere too. BTW I would avoid using global variables like that, or individually names variables for each book - it's too static and not very maintainable. An array would be much more sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are not calling `loadDefaultBooks`. Also the function `createBook` is not making any sense. You can use the same function `addBookClick` and pass argument.

This line var `txtBookTitle = a || document.getElementById("txtBookTitle").value;` when `a` has a value consider that value, other on click of button `a` will be `undefined`. In that case consider the value from the input text

```js
function addBookClick(a, b, c) {
  //Input fra skjemaet
  var txtBookTitle = a || document.getElementById("txtBookTitle").value;
  var txtBookAuthor = b || document.getElementById("txtBookAuthor").value;
  var txtBookISBN = c || document.getElementById("txtBookISBN").value;

  // Lag html-tabell
  // 0 = tabell 1
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

  // Legg til ny rad nederst i tabellen. (0) = øverste rad i tabellen.
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

  // Legg til celler i tabellen
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

  // Legg til values i cellene
  cel1.innerHTML = txtBookTitle;
  cel2.innerHTML = txtBookAuthor;
  cel3.innerHTML = txtBookISBN;
}



function loadDefaultBooks() {
  addBookClick("Judo Unleashed", "Neil Ohlenkamp", "0-07-147534-6");
  addBookClick("Kodokan Judo", "Jigoro Kano", "0-87011-681-9");
  addBookClick("Olympic Judo", "Neil Adams", "0-7207-1735-3");

}

loadDefaultBooks()
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Bokdata</legend>
  <label for="txtBookTitle">Tittel</label>
  <input id="txtBookTitle" type="text" value="">
  <label for="txtBookAuthor">Forfatter</label>
  <input id="txtBookAuthor" type="text" value="">
  <label for="txtBookISBN">ISBN</label>
  <input id="txtBookISBN" type="text" value="">
  <p>
    <button onclick="addBookClick()">Legg til</button>
  </p>
</fieldset>
<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Min bokliste
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Tittel</th>
      <th>Forfatter</th>
      <th>ISBN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblBodyList">

  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="tblSummary">

  </tfoot>
</table>
```